# Cant grab indexOf - is not a function

Tags: jquery, indexof

I have an array which i want to store the name and then a piece of information so i can then call the item to retrieve the information. When i try to search the array to check first the item is in the array i receive: `GenreArray.indexOf is not a function`

My code:

```
var GenreArray = {"00's":"Includes Amy Whinehouse, Westlife, The Killers...","90's":"Includes Britney Spears, Backstreet Boys, Mariah Carey..."};

if(GenreArray.indexOf("00's") > -1) //Crashed here
{
 //Code here
  console.log(GenreArray["00's"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GenreArray` is an object, an object contains key/val pairs, not indexes. You can do `hasOwnProperty`

```
if (GenreArray.hasOwnProperty("00's")) {

}
```

(So it might make sense to rename that variable to 'GenreObj')

Comment: If i was to change it to an array with []; how can i do `"00's":"Includes Amy Whinehouse` as i receive `missing ] after element list` error

Comment: @irishwill200 - Not sure what you mean. How do you want the array to look/

Comment: I want to store information. Key:Info, so i can then check if the key exists, then if so.. Pull the information using something `array[key][0] OR array[key] will display "info"`

Comment: `console.log(GenreArray["00's"])` will log the info you want.

Comment: Yes i know. Sorry im not explaining correctly.. I just realised i made an object not an array.. I was following: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp I want my array to be an ARRAY. So i can do `var arrayname = ["Keyname" : "Information HERE"]` I then would like that to work with arrays but how can i do that so .length can work?

Comment: @irishwill200 - But that's not how arrays work - you would have something like `var arr = [{"00's":"info here"}, ...]` - and then you'd have to access via index AND key name like `arr[0]["00's"]` - and it seems like an object is actually what you want

Comment: Hmm, ok. Thanks!

Comment: Just seems very complicated the `.hasOwnProperty()` part. Im use to index's. If there is a simple way that i can achieve my goal and still use indexs i would be happier i think! :)

Comment: @irishwill200 - Well objects dont have indexes - so if you're using an object, no. Objects are unordered key/val pairs.

Comment: Hmm i see! And if i was to go my way, the way you stated `[{"00's":"info here"}, ...]` would work then? What would be more efficient to use?

Comment: You'd have access to indexes then, but your code to check if an object exists based on a key would become more complicated. Efficiency is largely dependent on the size.

Comment: Ahh i see, well thanks very much! You actually blown my mind and left me gazing out the window for a few minutes haha! Will stick to objects and learn on that! Thanks again :)